trying to submit a form, and it's returning error
I'm trying to submit this from, but it is returning invalid password, I trim()'d the data, both for the registration method
const Auth = require('../models/AuthModel');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const create_user = async (req, res) => {
    let { username, email, password, confirmPassword, country } = req.body;

    // Strip any leading or trailing whitespace
    username = username?.trim();
    email = email?.trim();
    password = password?.trim();
    confirmPassword = confirmPassword?.trim();
    country = country?.trim();

    // Validate required fields
    if (!username || !email || !password || !confirmPassword || !country) {
        return res.render('register', { error: 'All fields are required', success: null });
    }

    // Check if password and confirm password match
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        return res.render('register', { error: 'Passwords do not match', success: null });
    }

    // Check email format
    const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        return res.render('register', { error: 'Invalid email format', success: null });
    }

    try {
        // Check if the user already exists
        const existingUser = await Auth.findOne({ $or: [{ email }, { username }] });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.render('register', { error: 'User already exists', success: null });
        }

        // Hash the password before saving
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        const auth = new Auth({ username, email, password: hashedPassword, country });
        await auth.save();

        // Generate JWT
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: auth._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });

        // Set the token in a cookie and redirect to dashboard
        res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
        res.redirect('/dashboard'); // Redirect to dashboard after successful registration

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('register', { error: 'Error creating user', success: null });
    }
};


const login_user = async (req, res) => {
    let { identifier, password } = req.body;

    // Strip any leading or trailing whitespace
    identifier = identifier?.trim();
    password = password?.trim();

    if (!identifier || !password) {
        return res.render('login', { error: 'Inputs are required', success: null });
    }

    try {
        // Determine if identifier is an email or username
        const isEmail = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(identifier);
        const user = await Auth.findOne(isEmail ? { email: identifier } : { username: identifier });

        if (!user) {
            return res.render('login', { error: 'Invalid identifier', success: null });
        }

        // Compare provided password with the stored hashed password
        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        console.log(`Password entered: ${password}`);
        console.log(`Password valid: ${isPasswordValid}`);
        console.log(`Stored password hash: ${user.password}`);
        
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            return res.render('login', { error: 'Invalid password', success: null });
        }

        // Generate JWT
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });

        // Set the token in a cookie and redirect to the dashboard
        res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
        res.redirect('/dashboard');

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('login', { error: 'Error logging in user', success: null });
    }
};


module.exports = {
    create_user,
    login_user,
};


Help us help you - share the error
